# integration of incomplete beta function in matlab

Tags: matlab

This line code works:

```
g=integral(@(z(z.^((2*0.1*0.7)-1)).*betainc(0.7./z,0.37,0.4),0.7,0.7.*exp(11/0.7),...
                                                                           'RelTol',1e-16)
```

for other upper limits as `0.7*exp(120/0.7)` or `0.7*exp(5/0.7)` it works as well.
However, if the limit is `0.7*exp(12/0.7)` or `0.7*exp(30/0.7)` I get the following error:

```
Error using betainc
X must be in the interval [0,1].

Error in @(z)(z.^((2*0.1*0.7)-1)).*betainc(0.7./z,0.37,0.4)


Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 323)
                fx = FUN(t).*w;

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `0.7*exp(120/0.7) = 1.9751e+74` upper limit the result is clearly wrong (`9.3143e-16`), it is interesting that no warning message is given.

What you want to calculate is an improper integral on an unbounded domain, see your function below:
[image]

It is not a good idea to try to give an enormous upper limit to approximate the improper integral.
The help page of [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/integral.html) recommends for this case to define the limit as `Inf`, using this the integral is calculated with the following warning message:

> Warning: Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use.
>   Approximate bound on error is   3.6e-07. The integral may not exist,
>   or it may be difficult to approximate numerically to the requested
>   accuracy.

Since the result of the integral is `2.6349` the error is negligible (if we can believe the warning message), by the way it seems to me a reasonable number.

Here is the code:

```
fun = @(z)  (z.^((2*0.1*0.7)-1)).*betainc(0.7./z, 0.37, 0.4);
ll = 0.7;
ul = Inf;
g = integral(fun, ll, ul, 'RelTol', 1e-16)
```